# How to fill value in HTML input with id inside WebView

Tags: android

I have HTML page inside my **WebView** with input, input has **id="inName**. How to fill this input from activity with some string ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try following:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: document.forms['myform_id'].value ='" + newValue + "'");
```

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: I would use 'document.getElementById("inName")' to get the element, and you'll need to escape the single quotes in newValue.

Comment: you're totally right - if you want to set a String you need to say .value='"+newValue+"')");

Comment: @Kevin Galligan can you please tell how to use this code? just add after that code where i get to the site? because in my case this code is not working=(

Comment: Something like the following.  The 'forms' way would probably be fine, but I prefer direct id referencing.  Also, I escape single quotes here. mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('inName').value ='" + newValue.replace("'", "\'") + "')");

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go is to use a JavaScriptInterface. For example:

```
 class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
 }
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
 webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```

Comment: Providing a sample is always better than posting some link which could be dead already