# fill some text in input box in webview android through javascript or something else

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to filled some text in input box of webview.
I have seached this and found
    here for [iphone] ([Pre-fill WebView text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145807/pre-fill-webview-text-fields)) . The script loads in iphone and works well. 
    and for android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052077/how-to-fill-value-in-html-input-with-id-inside-webview)
    but this couldn't work.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use value="some value" in input tag

```
<input id="username_5"  value="some value" type="text" size="20" name="username"></input>
```

Comment: How to do this in android
  in my case 
<input class="note" type="text" name="password" size="20" value="API password" onclick="this.value=''">
above is in webview
and i have tried with
view.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('note')[0].value=TestMe");
but No success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: document.forms['YOUR FORM NAME'].value ='"+NEW VALUE+"')");
```

Hope this will help.